# What does + in the memory type of DDR4 RAM mean?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr

Some mainboard producers add a `+` to the specification of supported memory types (e.g. for [ASRock X99 Extreme 3](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/X99%20Extreme3/?cat=Specifications) supports `DDR4-3000+`). Does `DDR4-3000+` somehow differ from `DDR4-3000`? The [wikipedia article on DDR-SDRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM) doesn't contain the sign`+` or mention anything related. I don't see the difference reflected in selection filters in online stores.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "+" usually indicates that the motherboard supports RAM with a frequency of over **3000MHz**. The OC in brackets means that the motherboard allows the RAM to be overclocked. The caveats being that you may need to increase the voltage and/or the timings in order to accommodate the higher frequency.

This article provides a good explanation on memory timings (e.g. 9-9-9-24):

[Memory Timings/Latency Expalined](http://www.thinkcomputers.org/memory-timings-explained/)

Comment: "The caveats being that a higher overclock/frequency will result in an increase in voltage and latency (in most cases)."

The latency is measured in cycles(not time) for SDRAM, so the actual latency depends on latency number / the frequency you can reach.

Comment: I didn't say it's measured in time. I simply stated that a greater overclock will have an adverse effect on latency.

Comment: That's just it, overclocking means you may need more latency cycles, but not actually more latency. 2 cycles at 100MHz is the same latency as 3 cycles at 150MHz. If you can run at 125MHz with only 2 latency cycles, the latency has decreased rather than increased.

(Everything else in your answer I agree with and was helpful)

Comment: So, are you saying I should change my answer to say latency cycles, instead of just latency?

Comment: I would just mention that you'll likely need to adjust the timings and/or voltages along with the new speeds.

Comment: Okay, I think that's fair.